# g++ has stopped working from prompt windows10

Tags: g++

So I installed MINGW which is now present in C:\MinGW\bin and contains the g++ files and make file. I also added into Properties-> Advanced setting -> Environment path -> Path -> "C:\MinGW\bin". When I open the prompt to execute g++ with the following file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

The message is the following:
"g++ has stopped working"

I am using windows10. And even when I try to get the version of the compiler, the same error message appears.
Your help is fully appreciated.
Regards,
Cyril

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue doing the following: After creating a project with MinGW compiler, go find the real folder of MinGW which was not C:\MinGW\bin for me but rather C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-6.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1\mingw32\bin.
Then click right on your project in Eclipse -> Properties -> C++ Build -> Environment -> Change the path of MinGW and MinGW home with the appropriate folder. And voila!